# Angular - Using observable (which gets value in asynchronous data call ) in another component

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, rxjs

I am developing an angular website with JWT token authentication , as soon as user is authenticated , the user data is stored in a behaviour subject to which all the other components subscribe. So far i have 10 components which are all working fine since im using the observable data in the HTML part.

But in this current component which allows user to change other user's role , i want to get all user's with role lower than the current user's role. so i am using an API call with current user's role as parameter to get list of required users. This is working completely fine when i come to this component using routerLink but when i refresh or come to this url directly it throws following error :

[image]

You can see the Console.log(result) from API call is getting called after the error (the user info object), so probably the component's ngOnInit is getting called before data from API call is published to behaviourSubject.

**Main App component :**
(calls the getCurrentUser every page load to check user credentials & token in local storage)

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
 import { AppService } from './Services/app.service';
 import { error } from '@angular/compiler/src/util';
 import { ThrowStmt } from '@angular/compiler';
 import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
 import { AuthService } from './Services/auth.service';
 import { LoggedInUser } from './Models/app.context';

 @Component({
   selector: 'app-root',
   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
 })
 export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
   title = 'webapp';
   currentUser : LoggedInUser;
   loginError : string;
   isAuthenticated : boolean

   constructor(private _appService : AppService,
      private _authService : AuthService) {
      this.isAuthenticated = false;
      this._authService.isAuthenticated$.subscribe(value => this.isAuthenticated = value)
      this._authService.currentUserSubject$.subscribe(user => this.currentUser = user )
   }

   ngOnInit() {
     this._authService.GetCurrentUser()
   }

 }
```

**AuthService:**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {


  public currentUserSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
  public isAuthenticated$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  currentUser = this.currentUserSubject$.asObservable();

  constructor(private apiService: HttpService,
    private router: Router) { }

  GetCurrentUser() {
    if(!localStorage.getItem(ACCESS_TOKEN)) {
      return;
    }
    return this.apiService.getData(environment.API_BASE_URI + "/api/v1/users/me").subscribe(
      result => {
        debugger;
        console.log(result)
        this.currentUserSubject$.next(result)
        this.isAuthenticated$.next(true)
      },
      error => (this.HandleLoginError())
  );
  }

  IsUserLoggedIn() : boolean {
    if(localStorage.getItem(ACCESS_TOKEN)) {
      return true
    }
    return false;
  }

  Login(loginDetails) {
    return this.apiService.postData(environment.API_BASE_URI + "/auth/login",loginDetails)
  }

  SignUp(signupDetails) {
    return this.apiService.postData(environment.API_BASE_URI + "/auth/signup",signupDetails)
  }

  HandleLogoutEvent() {
    localStorage.removeItem(ACCESS_TOKEN)
    this.currentUserSubject$.next(null);
    this.isAuthenticated$.next(false);
    this.router.navigate(['account/login'])
  }

  HandleLoginError(){
    this.currentUserSubject$.next(null)
    this.isAuthenticated$.next(false);
  }

  HandleBackClick(){
    
  }
}
```

**ProvideAccessComponent**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-provide-access',
  templateUrl: './provide-access.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./provide-access.component.css']
})
export class ProvideAccessComponent implements OnInit {

  currentUser : User;
  UserAccessForm : FormGroup
  error = '';
  selectedUser : string;
  selectedRole : number;
  usersList : Array<User>
  rolesList : Array<Role>

  constructor(private formBuilder : FormBuilder,
    private _authService : AuthService,
    private _appService : AppService) {

    this.UserAccessForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      selectedUser: '',
      selectedRole: ''
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._authService.currentUser.subscribe(user => this.currentUser = user);
    this._appService.getAllUsersForAccess(this.currentUser.roleId).subscribe(
      result =>  {
        this.usersList = result;
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  AccessRoleSubmit(accessRoleForm) {
    //check if newpass and conf pass are same
    console.log(accessRoleForm);
    //update password api call
  }


}
```

**provide-access-component.html**

```
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <h4>Give Access</h4>
                        <hr>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <form [formGroup]="UserAccessForm" (ngSubmit)="AccessRoleSubmit(UserAccessForm.value)" >
                            <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="name" class="col-4 col-form-label">User</label> 
                                <div class="col-8">
                                    <select class="form-control" formControlName="selectedUser" id="userList">
                                        <option *ngFor='let user of usersList' [value]="user.email">
                                            {{user.email}}
                                        </option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-4 col-form-label">Role</label> 
                                <div class="col-8">
                                    <select class="form-control" formControlName="selectedRole" id="emailList">
                                        <option *ngFor='let role of rolesList' [value]="role?.id">
                                            {{role?.role}}
                                        </option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <p class="h5-error">{{ error == '' ? '' : '*' + error }}</p>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="offset-4 col-8">
                                    <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Change Password</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

When i click Access and come to this component, list is loaded :

[image]

but when i refresh or come directly to this URL i see error and UI doesnt load the items :

[image]

Just FYI - I am not passing any data between the component directly, only through authservice.. there is a guard on routing which doesnt allow non-logged in users from visiting restricted urls , that is working just fine

```
{path: 'admin/provide-access', component: ProvideAccessComponent, canActivate: [LoggedInGuard]}
```

I dont usually post anything here till im completely stuck after searching alot on internet. I can provide more parts of code if required.

### Thank you

UPDATE 1 :

I tried the solution given by Micheal, since my currentUser observable was of type  , it was throwing error but even then after changed it to User and ran it , im getting same issue as before with a different error stack

[image]

[image]

I debugged it , still it first executes the switchmap line then the subscribe result in getCurrentUser()

Comment: `@Nikhil Kolte`  see my update

Comment: @RafiHenig Just tried it,   

     Overload 1 of 2, '(predicate: (value: User, index: number, source: Observable<User>) => value is User, thisArg?: any): OperatorFunction<User, User>', gave the following error.
        Type 'User' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
      Overload 2 of 2, '(predicate: (value: User, index: number, source: Observable<User>) => boolean, thisArg?: any): OperatorFunction<User, User>', gave the following error.
        Type 'User' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
throws this error on find(user => user) , when i move it after switchmap, this error is goes

Comment: But still same issue coming, not sure if its important, does find() need to be before switchmap() ??

Comment: `@sNikhil Kolte` see my update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider applying the following change so that `getAllUsersForAccess` will only be called once current user is available.

**ProvideAccessComponent**

```
this._authService.currentUser
  .pipe(
    tap(user => this.currentUser = user),
    filter(user => user != undefined), // <== use filter operator to wait until user is defined 
    switchMap(({ roleId }) = this._appService.getAllUsersForAccess(roleId))
  )
  .subscribe(
    result => this.usersList = result,
    error => console.log(error)
  );
```

Comment: I tried this but hit a similar error, i have updated the result in main post

Comment: This update worked! thank you so much for your time... its working perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is withing this piece of code

```
this._authService.currentUser.subscribe(user => this.currentUser = user);
this._appService.getAllUsersForAccess(this.currentUser.roleId).subscribe(/***/);
```

A subscription works asynchronous. The callback of the first subscription is not invoked before ngOnInit reaches the other lines. As a result `this.currentUser` is still `undefined`.

Please consider doing the following

```
const currentUser$ = this._authService.currentUser().pipe(shareReplay(1));
currentUser$.subscribe(user => this.currentUser = user);
currentUser$.pipe(
  switchMap(user => this._appService.getAllUsersForAccess(user.roleId)),
).subscribe(/***/);
```

PS.: If you ever feel a little bit overwhelmed by this auth stuff I can also recommend Manfred Steyer's angular-oauth2-oidc.

Comment: But why two individual subscriptions? It could be handled in a single subscription using an higher order mapping operator.

Comment: I used 2 because he currently uses 2. I tried to stay in his comfort zone. Personally I wouldn't even use a subscribe block, I would use async pipe instead.

Comment: Given OP isn't aware of the reactive paradigm, I'd say it's better to include best practices in the answer rather than to adhere to their implementation.

Comment: Thank you for considering it, i am currently trying Rafi Henig's solution , im still new but im getting the idea of whats happening there..I read about async pipe too, if thats better way out , ill definitely go for it later!

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'roleId' of null
    at SwitchMapSubscriber.project (provide-access.component.ts:38)

i tried this above change, still im getting the same issue .the same error that i got for Rafi Henig's solution .. updated the main post with screenshot